# SequentialTransition repeating more than the cylcecount

Tags: java, javafx-8, race-condition

I would have written malfunctioning but I know that I am about to be taken to school on a function of Javafx that I didn't know existed.

When I use a combination of `PauseTransition` and `SequentialTransition` to make a connect four game made of a grid of buttons float down button by button. Under a very specific use case, I have a very unexpected outcome.

Here is all the code required to run and replicate the error edited down to be self-contained and minimalist while still keeping basic game logic.

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ConnectFourApplication extends Application {
    public static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 8;
    public static final int NUM_ROWS = 8;
    private Button[][] buttons;
    private int row =0;
    private int column = 0;
    private PauseTransition buttonGravityPause;
    private Scene scene;
    private BorderPane border;
    private ConnectEnum turnColor=ConnectEnum.RED;

    public enum ConnectEnum{
        RED ("Red"), BLACK ("Black");
        private String turn;
        ConnectEnum( String value) {
            this.turn = value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        buttons = new Button[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLUMNS];
        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        Button turn = new Button("Take turn");
        for(int i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<NUM_COLUMNS; j++){
                buttons[i][j] = new Button("Empty");
                buttons[i][j].setMinHeight(20);
                buttons[i][j].setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                buttons[i][j].setOnAction(new ButtonHandler<>(i,j));
                gridpane.add(buttons[i][j], j, (NUM_ROWS-1)-i);
            }
        }

        buttonGravityPause = new PauseTransition(new Duration(700));
        buttonGravityPause.setOnFinished(event-> {
            if (this.row>0) {
                buttons[this.row - 1][this.column].setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
                buttons[this.row][this.column].setStyle("");
                this.row = this.row - 1;
            }else System.out.println("THis should never happen, row is: "+this.row);
        });

        SequentialTransition s = new SequentialTransition(buttonGravityPause);
        s.setOnFinished(floatDown-> {
            System.out.println("The button " +row+ " " +column+" has been chosen");
            buttons[this.row][this.column].setText(""+getTurn());
            buttons[this.row][this.column].setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+getTurn());
            changeTurn();
        });

        turn.setOnAction(e->{
            System.out.println("The button " +row+ " " +column+" has been chosen");
            int i =0;
            while(this.row-i>0 && buttons[this.row-(i+1)][this.column].getText().equals("Empty"))i++;
            s.setCycleCount(i);
            System.out.println("i is: "+i+"  but cycle count is: "+s.getCycleCount());
            if(i>0)s.play(); else{
                System.out.println("The button " +row+ " " +column+" has been chosen");
                buttons[this.row][this.column].setText(""+getTurn());
                buttons[this.row][this.column].setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+getTurn());
                changeTurn();
            }
        });

        border = new BorderPane();
        border.setCenter(gridpane);
        border.setBottom(turn);
        scene = new Scene(border, 510, 380);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Connect Four");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    private ConnectEnum getTurn(){return this.turnColor;}
    private void changeTurn(){this.turnColor = this.turnColor==ConnectEnum.RED? ConnectEnum.BLACK:ConnectEnum.RED;}
    private void setRowColumn(int row, int column){
        this.row=row;
        this.column=column;
    }
    private int getRow(){
        return this.row;
    }
    private int getColumn(){
        return this.column;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class ButtonHandler<T extends Event> implements EventHandler<T> {
        private int row;
        private int col;

        ButtonHandler(int row, int column){
            this.row=row;
            this.col=column;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(T event){
            if (buttons[getRow()][getColumn()].getText().equals("Empty")) buttons[getRow()][getColumn()].setStyle("");
            if (buttons[this.row][this.col].getText().equals("Empty")) {
                setRowColumn(this.row, this.col);
                buttons[row][col].setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
            }else System.out.println("This space is occupied");
        }
    }
}
```

This functions under all circumstances correctly except for the case where I 
 1. choose a button that is immediately above an already placed button and then 2. the next selection, if it is placed above several empty spots will cause the following console output(including the first few well behaved and expected statements):

```
The button2 1has been chosen
i is: 2  but cycle count is: 2
The button 0 1 has been chosen
false
The button1 1has been chosen
i is: 0  but cycle count is: 0
false
The button4 2has been chosen
i is: 4  but cycle count is: 4
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
THis should never happen, row is: 0
...
...
The button 0 2 has been chosen
```

To reproduce the bug/race condition: 
1. Select any button, press take turn. 
2. Select the button immediately on top of the now coloured button, press take turn.
3. Select a button that is not in the bottom row of buttons and watch the magic happen.

Previously this caused an array out of bounds but I added an if statement so that I could avoid the errors and attempt to shed some light on what was going on.

If anyone has any experience with this area of JavaFX I will be very appreciative as I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Making the `SequentialTransition s`  a field, and constructing a new one (rather than reusing the same instance)  when `turn` is clicked, solves the problem :

```
    turn.setOnAction(e->{
        int i = 0;
        while(row-i>0 && buttons[row-(i+1)][column].getText().equals("Empty")) {
            i++;
        }

        if(i>0) {
            s = new SequentialTransition(buttonGravityPause);
            s.setAutoReverse(false);
            s.setOnFinished(floatDown-> {
                buttons[row][column].setText(""+getTurn());
                buttons[row][column].setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+getTurn());
                changeTurn();
            });
            s.setCycleCount(i);
            s.play();
        } else{
            buttons[row][column].setText(""+getTurn());
            buttons[row][column].setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+getTurn());
            changeTurn();
        }
    });
```

I am not sure why reusing a `SequentialTransition` instance causes a problem. 
Hopefully someone who knows more about it can add an explanation.
A working demo code can be copied from [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tKK8Fu8yKt)